# What is the right way to message the user after 120 seconds of inactivity in my messenger bot?

Tags: node.js, botframework, chatbot, facebook-messenger-bot

I am using the bot framework to build a quiz bot and I want the person to get a message from the bot if they become inactive in 2 mins.
When I tried

```
bot.dialog('/', [(session)=>{
    session.dialogData.inactive = setTimeout(()=>{
        session.send('You there?')
    },30000)
}])
```

It gives me this error

```
TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
    at Object.stringify (native)
    at addWrite (D:\bots\zupquiz\node_modules\botbuilder\lib\bots\ChatConnector.js:261:29)
    at ChatConnector.saveData (D:\bots\zupquiz\node_modules\botbuilder\lib\bots\ChatConnector.js:276:21)
    at D:\bots\zupquiz\node_modules\botbuilder\lib\bots\UniversalBot.js:405:21
    at UniversalBot.tryCatch (D:\bots\zupquiz\node_modules\botbuilder\lib\bots\UniversalBot.js:425:13)
    at UniversalBot.saveStorageData (D:\bots\zupquiz\node_modules\botbuilder\lib\bots\UniversalBot.js:402:14)
    at Object.onSave (D:\bots\zupquiz\node_modules\botbuilder\lib\bots\UniversalBot.js:266:27)
    at Session.sendBatch (D:\bots\zupquiz\node_modules\botbuilder\lib\Session.js:381:22)
    at Timeout.<anonymous> (D:\bots\zupquiz\node_modules\botbuilder\lib\Session.js:513:23)
    at ontimeout (timers.js:365:14)
    at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:237:5)
    at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:207:5)
```

Comment: I think the issue here is you're storing the timer handle in dialogData, which gets serialized to storage. Try not storing the timer handle

Comment: then how do I keep track of the timer id between 2 methods of a waterfall, i want to set the timer in one and clear it in the other one

Comment: Can you save it in a serializable form? Perhaps a timestamp, or maybe even just a boolean (meaning the timer exists).