# Cancel a prompt or dialog after certain time - Bot Framework

Tags: bots, botframework

I have a question about cancelling a prompt or a dialog if there is no input from the user within a certain period of time.
I need a way to somehow have a time out within prompts.

> Example:
>   Bot prompts the user: "How old are you?".
>   The Bot now awaits a response from the user, but the user never response and the bot is still waiting.

In my case the bot should only wait 20 seconds and then close the dialog.
Is the `cancellation token` or a timeout implementation in the `HandleSystemMessageAsync Method` any helpful for that purpose and how would I implement that for a prompt?
Thank you for any ideas!

Comment: Are u using a PromptDialog for this or you are sending just a message to the user?

Comment: Yes I'm using PromptDialog like: "PromptDialog.Number(context, ResumeAfterAgePromptAsync, 'How old are you')"

Comment: similar question to mine http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41569285/what-is-the-right-way-to-message-the-user-after-120-seconds-of-inactivity-in-my i have the same requirements but want to send a message before canceling the dialog or prompt

Answer (score 0):

You could save a timestamp in the context.UserData, and then when you receive a new message check if the difference in time is >20 seconds and route the dialog appropriately.

Comment: Wouldn't 'PrivateConversationData' be better in this case than UserData?

Comment: That's a good question. According to [Bot State Service](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/csharp/builder/sdkreference/stateapi.html) the PrivateConversationData is scoped to a User and a Conversation. If the implementation of the State API stores PrivateConversationData for each conversation in a different data bag, this could potentially result in a lot of unnecessary data storage. If using UserData, it should be stored in the same data bag, and thus overwritten each time.

Comment: But if you started a conversation on one channel, Messenger, say - and then sent a message to the bot on another - say, SMS - wouldn't it be a different conversation? For example, if I open a page with an embedded  Webchat iframe, the bot receives a 'ConversationUpdate' activity and starts a new conversation. Is it possible that the same conversation is resumed on  different channels?

Comment: That's a good question. I don't actually know, but I assume not since the emulator assigns a new ConversationId each time you connect.

Answer (score 0):

Recently I completed a similar requirement in one of my chatbots. I have identified two types of timeouts.

1. Passive timeout
2. Active timeout

### Passive timeout

Passive timeout is similar as @Benjamin explain in his answer here. Basically save the timestamp of the last message and make decision in the next one. Similar approach is discussed here in the [Microsoft Botframework Documentation.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-howto-expire-conversation?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp)

### Active timeout

Technically this is a [proactive message](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-howto-proactive-message?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp) approach with a timer and involve the following setting:

- A timer ⏲️ to run in background
- A persistent storage️for maintain a list of:

  - conversation reference,
  - last message timestamp and
  - timeout status (eg: active, timeout warning, timeout, inactive).
- Logic in the bot  to register each message sent by the user.
- A controller to process a timeout from persisted storage
- A bot adapter  for:

  - Process timeout conversations,
  - Send proactive message indicating conversation is expired and
  - clear conversation state.